# What will be DataSet size in hive

Tags: hive, bigdata

I have 1 TB data in my HDFS in .csv format. When I load it in my Hive table what will be the total size of data. I mean will there be 2 copies of same data i.e 1 Copy in HDFS and other in Hive table ? Plz clarify. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a hive external table, you provide a HDFS location for the table and you store that data into that particular location.

When you create a hive internal table hive create a directory into `/apps/hive/warehouse/` directory.
Say, your table name is `table1` then your directory will be `/apps/hive/warehouse/table1`

This directory is also a HDFS directory and when you load data into the table into internal table it goes into its directory.

Hive creates a mapping between table and their corresponding HDFS location and hence when you read the data its reading from the corresponding mapped directory.

Hence there wont be duplicate copy of data corresponding to table and their HDFS location.

But if in your Hadoop cluster `Data Replication` factor is set to 3(default replication) then it will take 3TB cluster disk space(as you have 1TB data) but there wont be any effect of your hive table data.

Please see below link to know more about Data replication.

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs_design.html#Data+Replication

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether you are creating an internal or external table in Hive.

If you create an external table in Hive, it will create a mapping on where your data is stored in HDFS and there won't be any duplication at all. Hive will automatically pick the data where ever it is stored in HDFS.

Read more about external tables here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ExternalTables